# Why I couldn't call Model inside my Controller

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, n-tier-architecture

I have one problem and I have no idea what to do. I am try couple of method but nothing works for me. I have model Patient

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace BergClinic.Models
{
    public  class Patient
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="First Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public PatientGender Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PatientGender
    {
        [Display(Name ="Male")]
        Male,

        [Display(Name = "Female")]
        Female,

        Unknown
    }
}
```

And `IPatientRepository` and `PatientRepository` which contains following logic:

```
using BergClinic.DataAccess.Data;
using BergClinic.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using BergClinic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BergClinic.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class PatientRepository : Repository<Patient>, IPatientRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public PatientRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Update(Patient patient)
        {
            var objDb = _db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == patient.Id);
            if (objDb != null)
            {

                objDb.FirstName = patient.FirstName;
                objDb.LastName = patient.LastName;
                objDb.DateOfBirth = patient.DateOfBirth;
                objDb.Address = patient.Address;
                objDb.PhoneNumber = patient.PhoneNumber;
                objDb.Gender = patient.Gender;

                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `IPatientRepository` which containt Update method

```
using BergClinic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BergClinic.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IPatientRepository : IRepository<Patient>
    {
        void Update(Patient patient);
    }
}
```

Once I creat this in my Admin Area in `PatientController` I want to initialize object Patient but I couldn't. I want to create `Upsert` method for `Update` and `Insert Patient` but whatever I type It doesn't see my model only what it is see is Patient workspace

```
'Patient' is a namespace but is used like a type    


   using BergClinic.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BergClinic.Models;

namespace BergClinic.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public PatientController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {      
             Patient patient = new Areas.Patient
            return View();
        }


        #region API_CALLS
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var patient = _unitOfWork.Patient.GetAll();
            return Json(new { data = patient });
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Just to notice I use RepositoryPatten and thee way arhitecture. I try to restart Visual Studio but seem nothing happened, I try to remove Project Reference and try to add again, but noting happened againg.
Here is couple of sceen of my ProjectStructures which you can check:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the Visual Studio?

Comment: Sure, couple of times

Comment: Why don't you simply try this:

 `Patient patient = new Patient();`

Comment: I want and I try, but doesn't work. It seems that It not have reference to Model, but I add reference

Comment: An interesting situation!

Comment: Yes, I lost couple of hour and try everythink but nothing works

Comment: They are in different projects. Try to add dependency projects